# Handling error in apollo graphql returns invalid doctype even when content type is json

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, json-server

I have tried sending 404 status using json-server and it works with postman as seen below.

[image]

But when I'm doing it inside apollo sandbox, it's giving me this invalid doctype. Not sure why json-server is sending out html instead of json content type because I've already set it

[image]

Here is the json-server
[image]

Here's my datasource [image]

I tried casting the error to ApolloError but to no avail

`throw new ApolloError('InputValidationError', 'INVALID_INPUT', { error });`

The server
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forgot to add error formatting in the server. Refer to https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/data/errors/#masking-and-logging-errors

`formatError: (err) => { return err; },`